# xlsx file reading in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read xlsx file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267025/read-xlsx-file-in-java)

can anybody answer how to read xlsx file in java.

Comment: This was answered two years ago, with almost an identical title:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267025/read-xlsx-file-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Try [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html) - the Java API for Microsoft Documents

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

Answer (score 0):

"Why would you use docx4j to do this", I hear you ask, "rather than POI, which focuses on xlsx and binary xls?"

Probably because you like JAXB (as opposed to XML Beans), or you are already using docx4j for docx or pptx, and need to be able to do some stuff with xlsx as well.

Another possible reason is that the jar XML Beans generates from the OpenXML schemas is too big for your purposes. (To get around this, POI offers a 'lite' subset: the 'big' ooxml-schemas-1.0.jar is 14.5 MB! But if you need to support arbitrary spreadsheets, you'll probably need the complete jar). In contrast, the whole of docx4j/pptx4j/xlsx4j weighs in at about the same as POI's lite subset.

If you are processing spreadsheets only (ie not docx or pptx), and preceding paragraph is not a concern for you, then you would probably be best off using POI.