# How can I read .xlsx and .xls files in Java?

Tags: java, xls, xlsx, xssf

hi
i want to read xlsx file or xls file what ever it is. can XSSF support xls file ? or do i need to write the separate code for both kind of files ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read xlsx file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267025/read-xlsx-file-in-java)

Comment: @Srinivas have you tried the library that I've mentioned in the answer ?

Comment: The fastest and the easiest way I found to [read XLS, XLSX, ODS, CSV, etc...](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet-java/articles/java-read-xls-xlsx-ods-csv-html) is with [GemBox.Spreadsheet for Java](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet-java).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use Apache POI to [read and write xlsx and xls](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook) files.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your code to work for both, you'll have to use the `org.apache.poi.ss` package. This package has been created to unify XSSF and HSSF.

Comment: thank you for the reply,yes i want to write a code that should work for both xlsx ans xls.can you please give me sample code

Comment: org.apache.poi.ss is working for both kind of files thank you very much

Comment: @Srinivas : if your problem is solved, please mark this question as answered (the little green thing just left of my answer)

Answer (score 2):

For one of my projects I have created a basic utility that uses Apache POI and OpenCSV and can read both xlsx, xls and csv files.

Given a converter it can convert rows to objects, like this:

```
RowConverter<Country> converter = (row) -> new Country(row[0], row[1]);

ExcelReader<Country> reader = ExcelReader.builder(Country.class)
     .converter(converter)
     .withHeader()
     .csvDelimiter(';')
     .sheets(1)
     .build();

List<Country> list;
list = reader.read("CountryCodes.xlsx");
list = reader.read("CountryCodes.xls");
list = reader.read("CountryCodes.csv");
```

You may find the project on [github](https://github.com/eaorak/excelr).

Answer (score 0):

use this for xls and xlsx

```
Workbook wb_xssf; //Declare XSSF WorkBook 
Workbook wb_hssf; //Declare HSSF WorkBook 
Sheet sheet=null; //sheet can be used as common for XSSF and HSSF WorkBook 

if(fileBean.getFileExt().equalsIgnoreCase("xls")){
    wb_hssf = new HSSFWorkbook();
    sheet = wb_hssf.getSheetAt(0);
}else if (fileBean.getFileExt().equalsIgnoreCase("xlsx")){
    wb_xssf = new XSSFWorkbook(fileBean.getFileInput());      
    sheet = wb_xssf.getSheetAt(0);                                                          
}
```

Comment: No need for all that, just use `WorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(InputStream)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for xlsx files:

Firstly, you need the following jar downloads:

- dom4j-2.1.0.jar
- poi-3.17.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.17.jar
- commons-collections4-4.1.jar
- xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

Secondly, add the following imports in your workspace:

```java
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

Thirdly, begin building your method, for example for read use this:

```java
public void ReadExcelFiles(String pathxlsx,javax.swing.JTable jtable) throws IOException{
    //String nameSheet;
    File file = new File(pathxlsx);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    // nameSheet=wb.getSheetName(0);
    //XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet(nameSheet);
    XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    System.out.println(sh.getLastRowNum());
    System.out.println("Name: "+sh.getSheetName()); 
    Row row = sh.getRow(6);

    System.out.println(row.getRowNum());
    System.out.println("columna "+row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
    System.out.println("columna "+row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
    System.out.println("columna "+row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue());
    System.out.println("columna "+row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());

    System.out.println("Val: "+sh.getRow(4).getCell(6).getStringCellValue()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code and change it (depends on your needs):

```
public void parseXLSX() {

    String pathToXLSX = "file.xlsx";
    File file = new File(pathToXLSX);

    FileInputStream in = null;

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(file);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
        for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
            int rowNumber = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
            for (int j = 1; j < rowNumber; j++) {
                Iterator it = sheet.getRow(j).cellIterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(it.next().toString());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.getMessage();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: You need to add (if you use maven) this dependency:
`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>`
 or find necessary jar-file