# What i need to read Excel 2007 ( .xlsx ) extension in JAVA?

Tags: java, excel-2007, xlsx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read xlsx file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267025/read-xlsx-file-in-java)

I am trying to read excel sheet 2007 by java

I want to know what i need of libraries and JAR files to open and read the sheets

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

[Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents](http://poi.apache.org/). Supports xlsx format.

Comment: it is give me that error ""     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
 ""

Comment: The binary distributions at this location should be complete: http://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.7

Answer (score 1):

Try [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

Comment: It is contain Jar fail xmlbean ? i was try use it but it is give me error "    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
"

Comment: @AZIZ POI consists of several components. Have a look here: http://poi.apache.org/overview.html (go to the Component Map section) - the table states `xmlbeans` is a prerequisite, so you'd have to add it as well