# How to read .xlsx file in android program

Tags: android, excel, dalvik

I want to read .xlsx files in my android app.
I was trying to do it using ApachePOI API.
It was working fine with .xls documents but when I was trying to read .xlsx documents it was giving "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 2" error.Then I came to know that it is because of dalvik VM which don't supportmore than 65536 methods.
Please provide me a solution for this or any other open source API which I can use to read .xlsx docs in android.

Thanks,

Sameer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be using web services and read .xlsx files using Apache POI api in PHP and will return the data in json format.Please suggest if any one have some better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Apache POI added support for .xlsx, as written in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643112/2829009

Comment: POI already supported .xlsx files,but the problem is not with POI, its something to do with the Dalvik VM which android uses as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project? Eclipse menu -> Project -> Clean

Comment: yes,I tried that too.

Comment: I googled a bit and found [Smartling Translation API](https://docs.smartling.com/display/docs/Smartling+Translation+API). I don't know it, but maybe you can use it

Comment: Thanks for your efforts