# Reading xlsx files with xls reader (processing library)

Tags: java, processing

I can't figure out how to read .xlsx files extension with xls reader. 
Is it possible, or does the library only work with .xls files?

If that's the case. Any help on how to rewrite the library the read .xlsx file extensions?

Comment: you must update your poi jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267025/read-xlsx-file-in-java) it looks like Apache POI 3.5 has the support for XLSX files you need.