# How to read data from excel sheet using java?

Tags: java, excel

I am a beginner in Java coding and would like to know how to read the following excel sheet data using Java.

[image: Spreadsheet sample]

Also, I have tried the below code -

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;


public class ReadingFromExcelSheet {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Sanjana Rajeev\\Desktop\\Murali_YoutubeLinks.xlsx");
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(ip);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("MySheet1");
        int i,j;
        int rowcount =3,cellcount=2;
        for ( i=0;i<=rowcount;i++){
        for (j=0;j<cellcount;j++){
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
        Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
        String cellval = cell.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println(cellval + "\t\t" );
        }       
        }

        ip.close();
    }


}
```

And i am getting the below shown output :

```
Topics      
YouTube Links       
Java Execution
Java and JDK dowload
Eclipse download
Create a Workspace/Project/Package/Class files      
https://youtu.be/Pvcv-V69Vc0        
Java Execution
Java and JDK dowload
Eclipse download
Create a Workspace/Project/Package/Class files
Datatypes
Variables
String Concatenation        
https://youtu.be/Gx0ubuYwTjg        
Global Variables (Static & NonStatic)
Local Variables
Memory Allocation
```

I am getting the values of the cell but not in their proper order as like the excel sheet. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Having the tabs at he end of your output string while using `println()` doesn't do anything.  `println()` appends a newline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read XLSX file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267025/read-xlsx-file-in-java)

Comment: I'd say that you get exactly the correct order that you ask for. Either the youtube link is contained in a cell that spans multiple rows - or your left cell spans multiple rows and this is what you see in the output, in multiple rows as well. Add a marker after each cell and each row to your output to see the limits of each cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this improve the formatting?

```
    for ( i=0;i<=rowcount;i++)
    {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);

        for (j=0;j<cellcount;j++)
        {
            Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
            String cellval = cell.getStringCellValue();
            System.out.print(cellval + "\t\t" );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: `Row row = sheet.getRow(i);` can be moved out of second `for` loop

Comment: Done.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Sanjana Rajeev\\Desktop\\Murali_YoutubeLinks.xlsx");
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(ip);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("MySheet1");
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            //iterate over the columns of the current row
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                System.out.print(cellValue + "\t");
            }
            //append empty line
            System.out.println();
        }

        ip.close();
    }
```